# Prevent dismiss notification - Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

Is there a way to show a fixed notification, like Android update notification, forcing user to click on it ?

Because If user dismiss the notification and open the application later, all data is gone.

Answer (score 1):

With the plugin `cordova-plugin-local-notifications` you can show `persistent` notifications.

By using this code :

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    text: "Persistent Notification",
    ongoing: true,
    ...
});
```

[Plugin doc](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)